How do I put a TextBlock above everything else?
I have a Grid containing a bunch of elements, and I'd like to have a message occasionally show up. This message should not affect the existing layout, think of it as a toast.
I'd tried putting my containing grid in a StackPanel and then adding my TextBlock with a Panel.ZIndex="999", but that didn't work. The layout of the grid is still affected.
I supposed there is another argument I need to pass but I don't know which.

You actually don't need to touch index at all. If you look at how elements show when you add them to your grid, you'll notice that the last defined element will be on top. So you could wrap your grid, with another grid, then have your toast in there, it should show up when you need it.
I don't know how you structured your app so I am going to give you an example, rather than this being an exact answer, treat it as a suggestion as to how to approach this issue.
I would personally just wrap that grid of yours with another grid:
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ExecuteCommand}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </Menu>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonViewModel}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Button Content="Open Details" Command="{Binding OpenMoreDetailsCommand}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Grid.Row="2" Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress, StringFormat=\{0:P\}}" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Content="Populate people" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding PopulatePeople}"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToastMessage}" Visibility="{Binding IsToast, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>  

If you have a look at the last element, that's your toast. Style it however you want, put a border around it, add some animations, maybe add a margin so it is off set a bit from the top of the screen. This should give you an idea on how to progress.

Ah, thank you that works. I wonder why doing it with a StackPanel doesn't work while doing it with a Grid does.

Reason why Stack Panel doesn't work is because the text will show at the bottom of the screen. Also StackPanel only gives your elements minimal amount of space, while Grid gives as much space as it can provide. If that makes sense. But all of this is just a guess since I can't see your xaml.

Wrap main Grid or StackPanel with another Grid, then place the TextBlock after SubItem
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <StackPanel x:Name="SubItem">
        ...
        ...
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Text="Message To Display" />
<Grid/>

